# ASP.Net MVC 5 difficulty with addition object to db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

looking for help with my project. Trying to add object to db using input form. Here is my code:

HomeController

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {   
        EventsContext db = new EventsContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Event> events = db.Events;
            ViewBag.Events = events;
            return View();

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CreateEvent()
        {
            return View();

        }
         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateEvent(AddEvent addEvent)
        {
            db.AddEvents.Add(addEvent);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View("index");
        }
    }
```

At the moment I'm trying to hard code AddEventId and provide it within form, later I'll change it.
Here is input form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Id :</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="AddEventId" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Title :</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Title" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Date :</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Date" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Time :</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Time" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Address :</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Location" /></td>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Lecturer:</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Responsible" /> </td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </td><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

AddEvent class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PhClub.Models
{
    public class AddEvent
    {        
        public int AddEventId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Responsible { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Event Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PhClub.Models
{
    public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Responsible { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It works ok with hard coded events

```
public class EventDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EventsContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(EventsContext db)
        {
            db.Events.Add(new Event { Title = "Name of Event", Date = "18/11/2017", Time = "20:00", Location = "Adress", Responsible = "Name" });
            db.Events.Add(new Event { Title = "Name of Event", Date = "03/03/2017", Time = "19:00", Location = "Adress", Responsible = "Name2" });
             //db.Events.Add(new Event { Title = "Title3, Date = "04/03/2017", Time = "217:00", Location = "School", Responsible = "Name"});

            base.Seed(db);
        }
    }
```

If i understand correctly after i press submit, CreateEvent post method should be used and all elements of Event object should be passed to create and Event in db. After that  it should be populated on the page. However, new events does not. What I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your form posting?:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

According to that, it's going to post to the current URL.  If that's the index action then you're just posting back to the index action, which doesn't add anything to the database.

(As an aside, this is a good opportunity to familiarize yourself with some basic debugging.  Place breakpoints in the server-side action methods and debug your application.  See which method is invoked when the form is posted.  See what happens there and what values are sent to the server.)

Instead of manually writing the `<form>` tag like that, use the ASP.NET MVC form helper.  Something like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("CreateEvent", "Home"))
{
    <!--- all the HTML in your form -->
}
```

The rest of your form could really benefit from the use of these helpers too, that way the form is more dynamically generated from the structure of the model rather than requiring you to manually maintain it.  There are many examples and tutorials for MVC demonstrating this.  A quick Google search on "MVC form helpers" leads [here](https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/), among other places.

Comment: Thanks David, will have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you're adding things to your `db.AddEvents` in CreateEvent, but listing things from `db.Events` in the Index method.

Your seed is adding to `db.Events`, which is why your hard coded items are being listed.

Try changing your references to `AddEvents` to `Events`.  I think this will fix your issue.